# Why do I get an error when I pass a symbolic link to Gnuplot under Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, gnuplot, symlink, ln

I get an error when using a symbolic link in `gnuplot`:

```
on l: drive

plot "/j/projMainpips/Aggregate/dailyStats.txt" u 1:4 w l lw 1

warning: Skipping unreadable file "/j/projMainpips/Aggregate/dailyStats.txt"
No data in plot
```

The link was created as:

```
ln -s //xxx.yy.xx.y/Users/spence/JobsStuff/ /j
```

If I don't use the link, it works fine:

```
on h: in folder /j

plot "projMainpips/Aggregate/dailyStats.txt" u 1:4 w l lw 1
```

How can I enable use of symlinks in `gnuplot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested symlinks to UNC paths under Cygwin 32, and it works here.

Are you using the Cygwin version of `gnuplot`? You will get such errors if you try to use the [native Win32 port of `gnuplot`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.6.3/) instead.

If you can open the file in a Cygwin text editor, that shows that the symlink works:

```
vi /j/projMainpips/Aggregate/dailyStats.txt
```

Another way to run into trouble here is to edit `/etc/fstab` to drop the `cygdrive` prefix. If you do that, your syntax is going to try looking for a `J:` system drive. You'd need to use more than a single letter to avoid this problem or revert `fstab` to its original form.

Comment: Yes - I am using native win32 port of gnuplot

Comment: @ManInMoon: There's your problem, then. Cygwin emulates many POSIX mechanisms on Windows — including symlinks and [POSIX paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) — but you have to build a program under Cygwin to get those benefits. Cygwin does not — cannot, really — confer those benefits to programs not built under Cygwin. The solution is to use the Cygwin port of Gnuplot, which you can download with Cygwin's `setup.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing a native Windows application from Cygwin, you should use `cygpath` to **translate paths from Unix to Windows format**. You can try it with symlink too, maybe it'll work and translate the target path of the symlink to the Windows version path. I didn't try that, so I'm not sure if it works, but it's worth trying.

Example use:

```
# convert specified Cygwin path to the Windows path
cygpath -w ~

notepad `cygpath -w ~/test.txt`
```